# Inputting text file to an array, randomizing data from text file in array, outputting randomized data to separate text file

Tags: java, arrays, random, data-structures

I have successfully copied the code into the array (which is actually a list of all 201 countries and their level of internet usage). The list is in alphabetical order and I want to randomize the data so that there is no order to the data in the array. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Unsort {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String[] countries = new String[201];
    String[] percentages = new String[201];
    String[] line = new String[201];

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    Scanner fileIN = new Scanner(new File("F:/CountrySortedAlpha.txt"));
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("F:/CountryUnsortedAlpha.txt");

    while(fileIN.hasNext()){
        for(int i = 0; i < 201; i++){
            line[i] = fileIN.nextLine();
            System.out.print(line[i] + " " + i + "\n");
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 201; i ++){
            int randomize = (int) (Math.random() * 201);
            System.out.print("\n" + randomize);
        }
    }
}
}
```

The way that I have been trying is to make a random number to access the array at, but it ends up with so many collisions. The second loop was just  to make sure that the random variable worked. So my question is: how do I randomize the data in the array without collisions while using the random number generator? However, I cannot use algorithms pre defined by the java API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question properly that you have a file containing the country name and the internet usage at each line, and you want to create a new file that contains the same data (at each line) but in different lines (randomized), you may have a look at this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RandomizeData {

    public static void main(String[] args){
            ArrayList<String> fileData = new ArrayList<String>(); // arraylist is more dynamic 
            Scanner fileIN = null;
            PrintWriter out = null;

            try {
                fileIN = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Yahya\\Desktop\\SortedData.txt")); // for example
                out = new PrintWriter(new File("C:\\Users\\Yahya\\Desktop\\UnSortedData.txt")); // for example
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            while(fileIN.hasNext()){ // read the entire file of sorted data
                fileData.add(fileIN.nextLine());// add each line to the arraylist 
            }

            List<Integer> indexRef = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // create arraylist of integers to be as indices reference
               for(int i=0; i<fileData.size(); i++){
                      indexRef.add(i); // populate it
               }

            Random rnd = new Random();
            for(int i=0; i<fileData.size(); i++){ // for every index (line from the file)
                int rndIndex = indexRef.get(rnd.nextInt(indexRef.size())); // create random index
                out.println(fileData.get(rndIndex)); // get the data at that index in the arraylist 
                indexRef.remove(indexRef.indexOf(rndIndex)); // then remove the index from the indexRef arraylist in order not to use it again
            }
            out.close(); // close the printwriter          

        }           
}
```

**Example**
I have in SortedData File:

```
Canada 200
Ireland 500
Syria 100
U.K 400
U.S.A 300
```

**Output:** UnSortedData File:

```
U.K 400
Ireland 500
U.S.A 300
Syria 100
Canada 200
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this requires some extra lines of code, but you could

- create a list based on the array
- use [Collections.shuffle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-)
- if required make an array from the shuffled list.

Comment: If only... My professor said we cannot use algorithms from the java api. Which makes sense as it is a data structures and algorithms class

Comment: Please add such constraints to your question ;)

Comment: Another approach: Generate two random numbers that are between 0 and array size -1. Then exchange the two array values by using a tmp field ( copy content of position a to temp, copy content of position b to a and temp to b). Do this a couple of times.